# System freezes due to selenium chrome memory consumption

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

is there any way to free up the memory consumed by selenium chrome?

This question is specifically for websites like opeansea for eg. where there are more than 100k nfts in a single collection. The window keeps on scrolling consuming more and more ram  and eventually comes a point where the memory is consumed 100% and the system just freezes.